# Game of Life Parallel.For loop doesnt work as it is supposed to

Tags: c#, winforms

My game of life implementation works nicely, as a nested for loop, as soon as i try to convert it to a Parallel.For loop, it does all kinds of weird stuff - random celss become alive, stable structures just die out, and the whole thing just disappears after around 50 iterations
Here's my code:

```
void updateGrid()
    {
        int neigh;
        tempgrid = new bool[maxX, maxY];
        #region singlethread
        /*for (int y = 0; y < maxY; y++)
        {
            for (int x = 0; x < maxX; x++)
            {
                neigh = CalculateNeighbours(x, y);
                if (!grid[x, y] && neigh == 3)
                {
                    tempgrid[x, y] = true;
                }
                if (neigh > 3 || neigh < 2)
                {
                    tempgrid[x, y] = false;
                }
                else if (grid[x, y])
                {
                    tempgrid[x, y] = true;
                }
            }
        }*/
        #endregion;
        #region multithreaded
        Parallel.For(0, maxY, y =>
        {
            for (int x = 0; x < maxX; x++)
            {
                neigh = CalculateNeighbours(x, y);
                if (!grid[x, y] && neigh == 3)
                {
                    tempgrid[x, y] = true;
                }
                if (neigh > 3 || neigh < 2)
                {
                    tempgrid[x, y] = false;
                }
                else if (grid[x, y])
                {
                    tempgrid[x, y] = true;
                }
            }
        });
        #endregion
        grid = tempgrid;
        Invalidate();
    }
```

I've also tried nested Parallel.For loops - same thing happens

here's my CalculateNeighbours method:

```
int CalculateNeighbours(int xpos, int ypos)
    {
        int neighbourCount = 0;
        for (int y = -1; y < 2; y++)
        {
            for (int x = -1; x < 2; x++)
            {
                if (x == 0 && y == 0)
                {

                }
                else
                {
                    int tempX = xpos + x;
                    int tempY = ypos + y;
                    if (tempX == -1)
                    {
                        tempX = maxX - 1;
                    }
                    else if (tempX == maxX)
                    {
                        tempX = 0;
                    }
                    if (tempY == -1)
                    {
                        tempY = maxY - 1;
                    }
                    else if (tempY == maxY)
                    {
                        tempY = 0;
                    }
                    if (grid[tempX, tempY])
                    {
                        neighbourCount++;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return neighbourCount;
    }
```

Comment: Game of Life implementations depend on the state of the cells around each cell to work properly.  If you've not already done so, make sure you have *two* grids: the source one before state changes, and the target one after all of the states have been changed.

Comment: You got race conditons all over the place: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition | **Very few problems**  actually benefit from Mutltitasking or even Multithreading. "Multitasking has to pick it's problems carefully", is something I say. Apply it to the wrong problem, and you end up with code that is: More Memory Demanding, more Prone to errors - and at worst even **slower**.

Comment: i do already have two grids, also parallel loops shouldnt cause any problems because game of life is an infintiely parallel problem since im manipulating into a new grid anyways

Comment: He has two grids. But you're potentially going to write to your tempgrid at the same time on two separate threads which is no good. I would either put a lock around your tempgrid writes or use a thread-safe collection instead of a 2D bool array

Comment: i am writing to the tempgrid in 2 separate threads, im doing the same with another byte array on another project of mine and it works flawlessly, though that array is one dimensional

Comment: I know you're writing to it in two separate threads, that's the problem. If those writes both happen at the same time your application will explode

Comment: that is what i am doing in another project, another parallel loop, everything writing to it at the same time and works nicely

Comment: but it doesnt, it does the same thing, i copy old stuff to an array, edit that then copy back, here i create a new array, fill it according to the old data which remains UNCHANGED then when i'm done, ONLY THEN i copy back the array... i dont see how that is any different

Comment: @RippStudwell I think the write is safe in this particular case. Could you describe a way that this particular code may fail, after the error is fixed as per the accepted answer?

Comment: There is nothing inherently wrong with the code in the question, other than the bug I found. It is completely safe to have multiple, parallel, writes to an array. Bear in mind that each run through the update method is reading from one array and writing to another, there is no reading and writing to the same array going on. *That* would be unsafe, and would even mess up with the non-parallel implementation, but the way this is implemented will work just fine. Again, with the bugfix.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The bug is here:

```
        void updateGrid()
        {
--->        int neigh;
            tempgrid = new bool[maxX, maxY];
            #region singlethread
            ...
```

You have a **shared** variable for number of neighbors, and all your parallel loop iterations keeps updating that same variable, trampling on whatever value a different parallel iteration just wrote into it.

If you move the declaration of this variable into the loop as well, it works.

Answer (score 0):

> as soon as i try to convert it to a Parallel.For loop, it does all kinds of weird stuff

Wierd Stuff and Multitasking means [race conditons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition).

You can never take a piece of sequential code, make it paralell and expect it to work out. It is not a magical "make things go faster" bullet. Code must be **designed** with Multitasking in mind. Problems must be **picked**, that Multitasking can solve. The chance for something to just work in parlell (i.e., the problem being inherently designed for it), is 1:1000 at best.

Random code at worst is inherently sequential. At best, you end up with code that is more memory demanding, more prone to error and slower then the sequential thing.

The only kind of Multitasking I could see working for Convays game of life, is the GPU way. All cells have their code run in paralell, all ticks at the same time. But even there are plenty of pitfalls.

Comment: so can you explain why my raytracer, which copies a bitmap data into a byte array, i write into it with a parallel.for loop, copy it back and works flawlessly - based on your answer it shouldnt work either, im doing it with parallel loops as well, all the current game of life code does is look at old data, and put new data into a new array, the same thing what my raytracer does

Comment: @DharMahn "so can you explain" Pure copy opeartion. At no point will the output overwrite the input for another piece. Raytracing is how far I had to read. That is the kind of thing we do on GPU's. Those problems are *inherently* Multtiaskiable. Pleasingly so. Or we would not do them on the GPU.

Comment: neither does this overwrite the input, i copy it back when im done with the new grid - again - same as my raytracer

Comment: @DharMahn If you did that, you would not have the issue. As you have the isues, you do not do that. That is the only part about Race Conditions that is simple. Everything else is BrainFuck 3D.

Comment: This answer is too general in nature, and is not useful in this particular case.